# Getting specific Nth words from variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpvar="$*"
doit () {
    echo " ${tmpvar[1]} will be installed "
    apt-get install ${tmpvar[2*]}
    echo " ${tmpvar[1]} was installed "
}
doit
```

Which works under the command `./file.sh word1 word2 word3 word4`
The point is to get the first word for the 'echos' and the rest for the installation command.

Example: `./file.sh App app app-gtk`
Therefor displaying the first word in both 'echos' and getting the rest for the apt command.
But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `shift` here:

```
doit () {
   arg1="$1"  # take first word into a var arg1
   shift      # remove first word from $@

   echo "$arg1 will be installed..."
   # attempt to call apt-get
   if apt-get install "$@"; then
      echo "$arg1 was installed"
   else
      echo "$arg1 couldn't be installed">&2
}
```

and call this function as:

```
doit "$@"
```

Comment: I think it's important to exhibit the proper quoting needed to make this call (`doit "$@"`).   Also a good idea to check the return status of apt-get

Comment: Ok this solved my problem and answered my question. I didn't know the _shift_ command worked this way but, this helped me a lot. Thank you Sir.

Comment: @WilliamPursell just a thought, is there a way to get the return output from APT for later identification? I have another function where I store the output on a tmpfile and loop it in search of error messages. I never figured out a better way to do it !!

Answer (score 0):

file.sh would look like

```
#!/bin/bash

doit () {
    local name=$1
    shift
    echo " $name will be installed "
    apt-get install "$@"
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo " $name was installed "
}

# pass all the parameters to the function
doit "$@"
```